# Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target

Tags: python

I am just starting to work on some leetcode projects and have the following problem.

```
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
```

I have used the following code:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for i in nums:
            for x in nums:
                if i + x == target:
                    index1 = nums.index(x)
                    index2 = nums.index(i)
                    break
        answer = []
        answer.append(index1)
        answer.append(index2)
        return answer
```

and when I run it in the browser I get the same result as is expected each time.
[image]

However, when I submit my solution it comes back wrong.
[image]

Why is my the solution failing?

Comment: Look at the discussion section on HackerRank. Answers are often there.

Comment: Well, `list.index(3)` in the list `[3,3]` will always give you 0.